# Magento - How to render a page in popup or dialog?

Tags: magento, dialog, popup, php

I want to render a .phtml file into a Popup or dialog in all pages or How to convert page loading into popup or dialog box.
What is the way to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('default')->load();
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('mytheme');

$layout->getBlock('head')->setTitle('Regular Post Delivery Details');

echo '<html><head>';
echo $layout->getBlock('head')->toHtml();
echo '</head>';
echo '<body><div class="special-content">';

echo $layout
    ->createBlock('cms/block')
    ->setBlockId('estimated-regular-delivery-times')
    ->toHtml();

echo '</div></body></html>';
?>
```

Just make this a php file in your web root.